# Frequent spark plug change

Tags: ignition, hyundai, ignition-coil, tucson

I have a Hyundai Tucson , 2008 model.

About 20 months ago while my wife was driving the car, some smoke come out and she stopped the car and they tow it. (She doesn't remember white or black smoke)

After that in about 6 months car started to studder while I am driving. It was skipping a beat. I take the car to mechanic and change the spark plugs. One of the plugs was really wear out.

Next time, probably in 4 months after that same problem. This time I change plugs plus the ignition coil. Problem solved and come back after 3 months.

I have been changing plugs regularly so that I can use the car. I suspect at some point of time car overheated and engine block got damaged and there is water in the engine as a result and that is the root cause of all studder problems. Do you guys agree?

I will throw the car away in another 20 months. (Where I live cars are expensive and you get to use them only for 10 years). Shall I get it properly fixed or just keep changing the spark plugs and use it until the license expires?

Comment: Do you have an old plug that you could take a photo of and put on here?

Comment: @HandyHowie sadly no. But I will take picture next time.

Comment: how many miles are on the car?

Comment: @AlexVolpe 170k kms.

Answer (score 1):

I don't agree with your diagnosis.  You could have a faulty injector which is causing the cylinder with the problem to run lean.  This could cause the plug to overheat and wear out quickly.  Was the plug clean and shiny, not black?

Seems like it is more likely running rich, could still be an injector problem.

Comment: One of the plugs was dark. Others were better looking. It seems one of the plugs wears out faster. Which made me believe engine has water inside which cause the wear.

Comment: Was it beyond cleaning and reusing?  What you are describing sounds like the cylinder is running rich, not lean, which is the opposite of what I thought.  It could still be the injector thought.  Usually running rich does not ruin the plugs, they would just need cleaning.

Comment: It was beyond cleaning.

Comment: We're the electrodes worn down?

Comment: yes electrodes seem to be gone.

Comment: Might be best to check the plug before the problems start, if the engine is running lean then the spark plug could wear and then be contaminated with fuel when it stops sparking completely so it looks like its running rich.